# How to create a Golang struct instance from an array?

Tags: go, struct

Let's say I have a bunch of array of strings, for example:

```
data := [4]string{"a", "3.0", "2.5",  "10.7"}
```

And a struct definition:

```
type Record struct {
  name string
  x  float64
  y  float64
  mag  float64
}
```

I'd like to create an instance of this struct from each array.

I need to match the first item of the array to the first field of the struct and so on. Is it possible to do this?
Each array corresponds to one line of a file, so I can actually decide how to read these values in case a different approach is better.

Comment: What specifically are you asking?  How to [initialize a struct](https://gobyexample.com/structs)? How to [index an array](https://gobyexample.com/arrays)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy way is to use reflection to iterate over the fields of the struct, obtain their address (pointer), and use [`fmt.Sscan()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sscan) to scan the string value into the field. `fmt.Sscan()` will handle the different types of fields for you. This is in no way an efficient solution, it is just a short, easy and flexible solution. If you need an efficient solution, you have to handle all fields explicitly, manually.

This only works if the fields of the struct are exported, e.g.:

```
type Record struct {
    Name string
    X    float64
    Y    float64
    Mag  float64
    Age  int
}
```

The function that loads a string slice into a struct value:

```
func assign(recordPtr interface{}, data []string) error {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(recordPtr).Elem()
    max := v.NumField()
    if max > len(data) {
        max = len(data)
    }

    for i := 0; i < max; i++ {
        if _, err := fmt.Sscan(data[i], v.Field(i).Addr().Interface()); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Note that this implementation tries to fill as many fields as possible (e.g. it does not return an error if the struct has more or less fields than input data provided). Also note that this `assign()` function can fill any other structs, not just `Record`, that's why it's flexible.

Example testing it:

```
data := []string{"a", "3.0", "2.5", "10.7", "23"}

var r Record
if err := assign(&r, data); err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error:", err)
}
fmt.Printf("%+v", r)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/EapY5MDh871)):

```
{Name:a X:3 Y:2.5 Mag:10.7 Age:23}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to do this. You have to assign struct members one by one.

```
for _, x := range data {
    x, err := strconv.ParseFloat(x[1])
    y, err := strconv.ParseFloat(x[2])
    max, err := strconv.ParseFloat(x[3])
    strData = append(strData, Record{name: x[0], x: x, y: y, mag: mag})
}
```

You also have to deal with parse errors.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it it possible to do that in Go.

The following code example will assign to `s` the record filled with the fields of data.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

type Record struct {
    name string
    x    float64
    y    float64
    mag  float64
}

func main() {
    data := [4]string{"a", "3.0", "2.5", "10.7"}
    x, err :=  strconv.ParseFloat(data[1], 64)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    y, err :=  strconv.ParseFloat(data[2], 64)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    mag, err :=  strconv.ParseFloat(data[3], 64)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    s := Record{ name: data[0], x: x, y: y, mag: mag}

    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Comment: The issue is that the real struct has more than 30 fields.

Comment: @Daniela you may implement a loop for the conversion by filling an array of `float64` values. For the struct, you’ll have to write it in full, unless you use refection but that would make the code complex.